# How to save authenticated user in state using Redux and React?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to Redux, and I really don't have much time to spend researching, so I would appreciate if you could help me out. So basically I have a React component where I authenticate a user with an HTTP request to a backend. When I get the response back, I want the data to be saved in a Redux store so I can access it on other components/routes. How could this be done? Thank you.

This is my component:

```
class Register extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      errorMessage: null,
      user: null
    };
  }

  register = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log(event.target.email.value);
    let errorMessage = null;
    if (!event.target.name.value) errorMessage = 'Numele este obligatoriu.';
    else if (!event.target.email.value)
      errorMessage = 'Email-ul este obligatoriu.';

    else {
      const body = {
        name: event.target.name.value,
        email: event.target.email.value,
        password: event.target.password.value,
        confirmPassword: event.target.confirmPassword.value
      };

      return axios
        .post('http://localhost:5000/api/v1/auth/register', body)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
          this.setState({ // Instead of this, the user should be stored using Redux
            user: response.data.data.user
          });

        })
        .catch((error) => {
          this.setState({ errorMessage: error.response.data.message });
        });
    }
    this.setState({ errorMessage });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="register-page">
        <form onSubmit={this.register}>
          <h3>Cont nou</h3>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Nume" name="name" />
          <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" />
          <input type="password" placeholder="Parola" name="password" />
          <input
            type="password"
            placeholder="Confirmă parola"
            name="confirmPassword"
          />
          <span className="error-message">{this.state.errorMessage}</span>
          <input type="submit" value="Trimite" name="submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Register;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way if you need to save the authentification status of a user is to use `useContext` hooks.

- create a `Authcontext.js` file and define what you will have in you context (but just the data type, you can see we do'nt need to define `setIsAuthenticated` here.

```js
import React from 'react';

export default React.createContext({
  isAuthenticated: false,
  setIsAuthenticated: (value) => {},
});
```

- In your main component you can now wrap you whole app with the Context. We define the `setIsAuthenticated` function and the initial value of `isAuthenticated` here.

```js
const App = () => {

  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(AuthAPI.setupUser());


  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{
      isAuthenticated,
      setIsAuthenticated
    }}>

    <AppContent />

    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));

export default App;
```

As the context is a global state (as redux) you can also get the context from every component, for example.

```js
import React, { useContext } from 'react';

const Logout = () => {
  const { setIsAuthenticated } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const logout = () => {
        AuthAPI.logout();
        setIsAuthenticated(false);
    };

   return(...)
```

To determine if the user is connected you have to build you own logic, but if you are using jwt, the `setupUser` could be something like this.
It would be called every time the app starts to setup axios for your api call for example and return the status of thee user.

```js
function setupUser() {
  // check if token exist
  const token = window.localStorage.getItem('authToken');
  if (token) {
    const { exp: expirationDate } = jwtDecode(token);

    if (expirationDate * 1000 > new Date().getTime()) {
      axios.defaults.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
      return true;
    } 
  } 
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Where does AuthAPI come from?

Comment: I added an example for you to better understand.

Comment: I actually ended up using Context instead of Redux. Thank you for your answer, but one more question: isn't it unsafe to store jwt in localStorage?

Comment: Using redux you mean ? No it's not because everybody can decode a jwt token using `https://jwt.io/` for example and  in a jwt token only general informations as the name, email or the role are encoded.

Comment: Yeah, but localStorage can be accessed with XSS attacks. That was my point. So I would go with cookies instead.

Comment: Cookies are vulnerable to `CSRF` attacks, jwt are commonly store in the localStoare because it is only needed by the client side.  Both have pros and cons, you can read more here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220660/local-storage-vs-cookies